# Apache Camel Custom Component Consumer does not call other processors

Tags: java, kotlin, apache-camel

I wrote a custom component in [Apache Camel](http://camel.apache.org/). camel successfully create its consumer and using my URI, but no processor get called.
here is my consumer code snippet (in Kotlin):

```
class SoroushBotConsumer (private val endpoint: MyEndpoint, processor: Processor) : DefaultConsumer(endpoint, processor) {
    val objectMapper:ObjectMapper = ObjectMapper();
    init {
        startListening()
    }
    private fun startListening() {
        val client = ClientBuilder.newBuilder().register(SseFeature::class.java).build()
        val target = client.target("MY_URL"))
        while(true){
            var e: EventInput?  target.request().get(EventInput::class.java)!!

            val inboundEvent = e.read()
            val exchange = endpoint.createExchange()
            exchange.getIn().body = objectMapper.readValue(inboundEvent.rawData,MessageModel::class.java)
            try {
                processor.process(exchange)
            } catch (e: Exception) {
                if (exchange.exception != null) {
                exceptionHandler.handleException("Error processing exchange",exchange, exchange.exception)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

everything works fine in the Consumer but no processor get executed.
here is how I create the route!

```
var context = DefaultCamelContext()
context.addRoutes(object : RouteBuilder() {
    override fun configure() {
        from("myapp://getMessage/).process{
            println(it.getIn())
        }.to("myapp://sendMessage/")
    }
})
context.start();
Thread.sleep(100000);
context.stop();
```

it neither calls the process nor creates my producer. (it does not even call `MyEndpoint::createProducer()`)

when I replace my `from` statement with another endpoint like `file`, everything works fine.

**Update:** when I extend my consumer from `ScheduledPollConsumer` Implement `pull` method, everything goes fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its, because we must finish the constructor of consumer and write the logic of receiving messages in `doStart()`

```
class SoroushBotConsumer (private val endpoint: MyEndpoint, processor: Processor) : DefaultConsumer(endpoint, processor) {
    val objectMapper:ObjectMapper = ObjectMapper();
    override fun doStart() {
        val client = ClientBuilder.newBuilder().register(SseFeature::class.java).build()
        val target = client.target("MY_URL"))
        while(true){
            var e: EventInput?  target.request().get(EventInput::class.java)!!

            val inboundEvent = e.read()
            val exchange = endpoint.createExchange()
            exchange.getIn().body = objectMapper.readValue(inboundEvent.rawData,MessageModel::class.java)
            try {
                processor.process(exchange)
            } catch (e: Exception) {
                if (exchange.exception != null) {
                    exceptionHandler.handleException("Error processing exchange",exchange, exchange.exception)
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This is not a good idea to have a endless loop in the doStart method where you will hijack the current thread which then never terminates. Instead you should setup a background thread that runs this job and from the doStart you can setup this thread and let it run. In other words how a component "receives" messages is 100% component specific as each of them have their own way. And in the doStop method you then have logic to stop that background thread and cleanup any of your resources.